# quickly find argument description in unix man page

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

How do I jump exactly to the definition of an option within a `man` page?

Example: try to find what `-L` means when performing `man curl`.

Naive approach: `/-L` requires 5 `n`s (nexts) before I get to the actual definition.

A little better: `/-L,` requires 4 `n`s (nexts).

Is there any reliable way to jump exactly to the argument documentation in a `man` page?

Comment: some command have a proper info page (try ` info ls` , quit with CTRL-X CTRL-C) which allow more or less directe navigation, there is a drawback, you have to know how to navigate in emacs mode.

Comment: Viewing manuals uses your normal pager (e.g. `$PAGER` or `/usr/bin/pager` - which is normally a symlink), so you'll want to identify which pager you use.

Answer (score 2):

While I wasn't able to find any way to pass the argument into man itself, the searching mechanism (using /) when viewing a manual accepts regular expressions. I typically search for the argument by attempting to match it as the first thing on a line after spaces.

I've tested this search against your example of finding the -L argument for curl and nailed it in the first try:

```
/^ +-L
```

brief regex explanation:

^ = beginning of line

space = a literal space character

+ = one or more of the preceding character (a space in this instance)

-L = the argument you are trying to locate

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to search for space-dash-L-comma?

As in `/ -L,`

I don't have `curl` to check that particular man page, but in general all man pages are basically one big page, with differing formats. Options are usually listed at the start, but no real easy way to jump to their definitions.

Most man pages are available on the web somewhere too, a web search for the command and the option in question maybe more useful & possibly quicker too?

Comment: `/ -L,` took 3 searches. But I think you're right, there's not easy way to directly jump to their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you view your man pages in Emacs (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`man`), you get some navigation built-in (e.g. <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> for next/previous section, <kbd>s</kbd> to jump straight to `SEE ALSO`).  It's then a small matter of writing a couple of Lisp functions to achieve what you want...